# RecyclerView: Newly created tasks coming in the next recycler view model

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am new to kotlin and android studio and I am trying to create a To Do list app. I am using RecyclerView to show the new tasks added. Here is the code for recycler view and the dashboard:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".dashboard">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_dashboard"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dashboard_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

To create a new task, the folowing code has been written where all the sql code is there to store the data:

```
 fun addToDo(toDo: ToDo): Boolean {
        val db = writableDatabase
        val cv = ContentValues()
        cv.put(COL_NAME, toDo.name)
        val result = db.insert(TABLE_TODO, null, cv)
        return result != (-1).toLong()
    }
```

I am using a dialog box which is working perfectly.
To enable the dialog box and add a new task using a floating button, I have written the following code:

```
newTask.setOnClickListener{
            val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialogue_dashboard, null)
            val toDoName = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.et_todo)
            dialog.setView(view)
            dialog.setTitle("New Task")
            dialog.setPositiveButton("Add"){ _: DialogInterface, _ : Int ->
                if(toDoName.text.isNotEmpty()){
                    val toDo = ToDo()
                    toDo.name = toDoName.text.toString()
                    dbHandller.addToDo(toDo)
                }
            }
            dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel"){ _: DialogInterface, _: Int ->
                Toast.makeText(this,"No Task Added",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            dialog.show()
        }
```

and the following adapter for RecyclerView:

```
class DashboardAdapter(val context: Context,val list: MutableList<ToDo>) :
        RecyclerView.Adapter<DashboardAdapter.ViewHolder>(){
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(p0: ViewGroup, p1: Int): ViewHolder {
            return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.rv_child_layout,p0,false))

        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, p1: Int) {
            holder.toDoName.text = list[p1].name
        }

        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return list.size
        }
        class ViewHolder(v : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v){
            val toDoName : TextView = v.findViewById(R.id.tv_todo_name)
        }
    }
```

When I add a first task, it adds easily and stays on top just below the toolbar, but when I add the second task, I cannot see it just below the first task where I want it to be but instead I have to scroll down to find it, similar to as if it is added in a new recycler window. I cannot find the solution to this problem anywhere on the internet.

[Added Task #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEhsE.png)

[Added Task #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ar0D7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have wrong android:layout_height value in R.layout.rv_child_layout, which makes every item fill all screen space.

Please make sure, the top layout in rv_child_layout has "wrap_content" height.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `rv_child_layout.xml` root Views `android:layout_height="match_parent"` to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`.